# A method was called at an unexpected time

Tags: exception, windows-8, windows-runtime, local-storage, winrt-async

I'm trying to iterate all files in a directory using GetFilesAsync, but every time I call the GetResults method, it throws an exception that says

> System.InvalidOperationException: A method was called at an unexpected
>   time

The code is simply

```
var files = myStorageFolder.GetFilesAsync(); //runs fine
var results = files.GetResults(); //throws the exception
```

I'm new to Win 8 dev so I might be missing something obvious.

**Edit (solved)**
I'm running my console application, but now that the program runs async, the `files.GetResult()` method no longer exists.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var files = GetFiles(myStorageFolder);
   var results = files.GetAwaiter().GetResults();//Need to add GetAwaiter()
}

static async Task GetFiles(StorageFolder sf)
{
   await sf.GetFilesAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to wait for the async method to complete. So you could use the new await as one option:

```
var files = await myStorageFolder.GetFilesAsync();
```

You might want to check the documentation on dealing with async methods [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx).

Answer (score 42):

If you don't want to use the `async`keyword (in my case, the code was inside a property, so `async`wasn't an option), you can use a `TaskAwaiter` instead, by chaining  these two methods:

```
var folder = Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("folderName").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

This won't throw a `InvalidOperationException` nor cause a deadlock.

Comment: Do I need any `Using` statements to use the `GetAwaiter` method?

Comment: @user1 I can't remember, this is from 2 years ago. But looking through the docs, this is the extension method you need: [`WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions.GetAwaiter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582011(v=vs.110).aspx). It's defined in the `System` namespace, so you probably have it in scope already

Comment: I noticed the `GetAwaiter()` was on a `Task` and I was trying to use it on an `IAwaitableOperation` so I had to call `AsTask` then `Results`, damn `UWP`. Thanks though!

Comment: This also solves the issue when in an `if` statement as well.  I was receiving the error when I just ran the application, but not if I placed a breakpoint just before the `if` statement and used Step Into to run through the `if` statement.

`if(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.TryGetItemAsync("savedFavorites.xml").GetAwaiter().GetResult() == null)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an variation of Task like Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation the code can be like this:

```
var file = StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(protocolArgs.Uri.LocalPath).AsTask().Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should `await` the `var files = myStorageFolder.GetFilesAsync();` as the operation might still be running when you get to next instruction `var results = files.GetResults(); //throws the exception`

```
var files = await myStorageFolder.GetFilesAsync(); //runs fine
var results = files.GetResults(); //this will run when call above returns
```